# Como criar uma função que repete determinado valor

Tags: javascript, funções

Quero criar uma função que receba dois valores, o primeiro será uma palavra qualquer, e o segundo será a quantidade de vezes que o sistema irá imprimir essa palavra.

```
var valor = "palavra" // exemplo
var qtd = 2 // exemplo
function repete(valor,qtd){
  for(var i = 0; i <qtd; i++ ){
     return valor
  }
}
```

Tentei desenvolver utilizando o for e mesmo preenchendo as variáveis não imprimi o resultado.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta tentando descrever melhor o que você realmente precisa, pois há 4 respostas que cumprem o que é pedido e nenhuma atende a sua necessidade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solução alternativa, e eu acredito ser mais simples, seria criar um array e [preencher](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) o mesmo com o valor desejado, e retornar uma [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) do mesmo de maneira que não seja necessário concatenar valores a string, por exemplo:

```js
function repete(palavra, qtd){
  // Cria um array com length determinado por "qtd"
  const array = new Array(qtd).fill(palavra);
   
  // Troque o - por espaço ou outro valor para determinar como as palavras devem ser separadas
  return array.join(' - ');
}

document.write(repete('Palavra 1', 5) + "<br />");
document.writeln(repete('Palavra 2', 2) + "<br />");
document.writeln(repete('Palavra 3', 10) + "<br />");
```

Concatenar Strings dentro a um for não é um problema desde que a quantidade de repetições seja pequena e o texto não seja muito grande, porém você pode encontrar problemas se o número de repetições ou o texto forem muito grandes.

> Tanto a minha, como as outras respostas dadas até o presente momento resolvem o problema descrito no enunciado, se falta alguma coisa então você deve editar a sua pergunta e adicionar detalhes sobre o que você realmente precisa do contrário a sua pergunta será fechada.
>
> Evite editar a suas perguntas adicionando outras perguntas encima da própria pois isso invalida as respostas dadas anteriormente, visto que você é nova por aqui, reserve um pouco do seu tempo para ler mais sobre o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stackoverflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs)

Comment: Obrigada, ainda estou me adaptando ao site, mas já descobri qual era o problema. Lerei o guia assim que possível, muito obrigada.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz de uma maneira bem simples usando seu proprio exemplo

```
var valor = "palavra" // exemplo
 var qtd = 2 // exemplo 
 function repete(valor,qtd){
 let palavra='';
    for(i=0;i<qtd;i++){
        palavra += valor+' ';
    }
    return palavra;
 }
 repete(valor,qtd);
```

Comment: Então, seria mais o menos isso só que eu preciso que o "qtd" determine a quatidade vezes que o valor vai se repetir. Seja uma apalavra ou número. E depois imprimir esse esse valor "qtd" vezes.

Comment: @BiancaKelly ele ja esta fazendo isso, eu testei com numero e palavras e alterei a quantidade de vezes e ele respeitou normalmente, n entendi aonde esta o erro poderia me explicar melhor?

Comment: @BiancaKelly vc quer que ele imprima em algum lugar do html?

Comment: Não, não, o que estava dando problema é que eu estava usando o return ao invés do console.log. Obrigada

Comment: @BiancaKelly se o codigo deu certo então ok, vote no codigo que lhe ajudou para que outras pessoas possam usar ele tambem

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia Bianca, se a sua intenção é retornar uma string com as palavras em sequências segue o código que funcionou pra mim: se a palavra passada for "Banana" ele retorna "BananaBanana", mas não sei se é exatamente isso que você precisa.

```js
function repete(palavra, qtd) {
    for(i = 0; i < qtd; i++) {
        valor = valor + palavra;
    } 
    return valor;
}
```

Fico a disposição caso precise de algo mais.

Comment: Vamos supor que eu preciso que a palavra "Banana" seja repetida cinco vezes. Acho que essa função não se adequaria muito bem... Mas obrigada mesmo assim

Answer (score 0):

O método `repeat()` retorna uma nova `string` com um número especificado de cópias da `string` em que foi chamada.

```js
var valor = "palavra" // exemplo
var qtd = 5 // exemplo 
console.log((valor+" ").repeat(qtd));
```

> bem simples

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde. Segue resolução:

```js
function repete(valor,qtd){
    for(i = 1; i <= qtd; i++) {
        console.log("" + valor + "");
    } 
}
```